RDP Shadowing does not use keyboard and mouse drivers, how to implement it?
Good time of day. I have a problem that I can't solve in any way. The bottom line is that the protection of the game does not respond to mouse clicks and keyboard shortcuts with a shadow RDP connection, because the shadow rdp does not use keyboard and mouse drivers, which we can observe in the task manager. The usual RDP connection, which connects from the shortcut in the start menu, connects to the PC and launches the remote mouse and keyboard drivers, and in this case, mouse and keyboard clicks go into the game and work. I've been looking for a solution for many days, but I couldn't find it. My goal is to connect to a remote PC via a REGULAR rdp connection and so that the main session (console) does not lock the screen. When connected, it is always blocked and I cannot control the game through a remote PC and through another PC at the same time. Tell me which programs can connect to a remote PC without blocking the main session. I tried to connect via windows server without blocking the main user so that it doesn't work. Shadow access doesn't work anymore either. I am trying to find a program that, when connected to a remote desktop, will not block the screen of the first user and will use its mouse and keyboard drivers or the drivers of a regular RDP connection. Tell me how to implement this...

Is this about "over the shoulder" remote viewing and control, about mouse and keyboard drivers, something else, or all these things at once? Welcome to this site. I am assuming this post was not written in English originally, but was translated. I think some of the translation is difficult for us English speakers to understand completely. Posts here should have a single, specific question, and asking that we recommend software is off-topic. Please EDIT your post to focus on a single question that is on-topic for the site.

"Regular" RDP doesn't have an "over the shoulder" mode, so regular RDP will never do what you want. Microsoft offers a Remote Control Viewer as part of the SCCM product suite which allows over the shoulder remote viewing and control, but you must install this separately. Mouse and Keyboard drivers in RDP have always been the generic virtual devices of RDP and it has always been necessary to use other work arounds to get other custom button and control setups working over RDP.
